# Error while pushing mule project to github first time

Tags: git, ssl, github, openssl

Trying to push my Mule project to Github for firs time and getting following error while executing git command from git bash:

```
    git push -f github master

    Error below:
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXXXX.git/': error:1425F175:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:inappropriate fallback
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy, a MITM firewall, or antivirus software?

Answer (score 0):

Try first (unless, as commented, you are behind a proxy or firewall) to upgrade your Git.

Say Git could be [using an incompatible client](https://github.blog/2018-02-01-crypto-removal-notice/#known-incompatible-clients), like:

- Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows on Windows
- Git on Red Hat 5, < 6.8, and < 7.2